# Create an Activity inside in Activity?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, dialog

Is there other way to create an `Activity` inside an `Activity` without using `Dialog`?

Comment: What's the first way you've tried?

Comment: Well I created an Activity inside a dialog, but I don't want some dialog to pop out whenever a button is clicked. I want it to behave as a normal activity

Comment: Can you clarify what you need to do? You can jump from one activity to another via `Intents`. You could move your code from inside your dialog to the place you need it to trigger your new Activity. Please share what you did in the Dialog implementation and what you need to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't create "Activity inside an Activity". You can start Activity from another Activity and if you assign `<activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">` to the Activity layout then it will appear as a dialog but Activities are independent entities each with it's own lifecycle. Perhaps if you provide code snippets and better description you will get a better answer?